# Golang echo middleware redirect with empty page

Tags: go-echo

I testing a redirect about echo when I just use the method to redirect it can show the login.html page successfully, but if I use a middleware test, it always shows empty page of `login.html`, what am I missing?

```golang
    e.Group("*.html", func(next echo.HandlerFunc) echo.HandlerFunc {  //1
        return func(c echo.Context) error {
            uri := c.Request().URL.String()
            log.Println("uri:" + uri)
            if uri != "/login.html" && uri != "/favicon.ico" {
                c.Redirect(http.StatusSeeOther, "login.html")
                return nil
            }
            return nil
        }
    })
    e.Use(session.Middleware(sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("secret"))))
    e.GET("/aa", func(c echo.Context) error {   //2
        c.Redirect(http.StatusSeeOther, "login.html")
        return nil
    })
```

Comment: Are you serving static files with echo? Can you show the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are missing the call of `next` to continue the request chain.

See the example here: https://echo.labstack.com/cookbook/middleware/

```golang
// ServerHeader middleware adds a `Server` header to the response.
func ServerHeader(next echo.HandlerFunc) echo.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c echo.Context) error {
        c.Response().Header().Set(echo.HeaderServer, "Echo/3.0")
        return next(c)
    }
}
```

See the `return next(c)`, it continues to process the request throw all middlewares and eventually the `login.html` static handler.

As you are not calling, it stops the chain and does nothing.